# Redirection in django and passing arguments

Tags: python, django

I spent some time reading through the documentation and forums, but not sure I understand this. I have this bit of code in the views of my app:

```
def billboard_index(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = SpotiForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        date = form.cleaned_data['spotiread_date']
        try:
            url = 'https://www.billboard.com/charts/hot-100/' + date
            billboard = requests.get(url)
            billboard.raise_for_status()
        except:
            print("No response")
        else:
            soup = BeautifulSoup(billboard.text, 'html.parser')
            positions = [int(i.text) for i in soup.find_all(name='span', class_='chart-element__rank__number')]
            songs = [i.text for i in soup.find_all(name='span', class_='chart-element__information__song')]
            artists = [i.text for i in soup.find_all(name='span', class_='chart-element__information__artist')]
            top100 = list(zip(positions, songs, artists))
            if Top100model.objects.exists():
                Top100model.objects.all().delete()
            for position in top100:
                top100data = Top100model(
                    idtop=str(position[0]), artist=str(position[2]), song=str(position[1])
                )
                top100data.save()
        params = {
            'client_id': SPOTIPY_CLIENT_ID,
            'response_type': 'code',
            'redirect_uri': request.build_absolute_uri(reverse('spotiauth')),
            'scope': 'playlist-modify-private'
        }
        query_string = urlencode(params)
        url = '{}?{}'.format('https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize', query_string)
        return redirect(to=url)

# if a GET (or any other method) we'll create a blank form
else:
    form = SpotiForm()

return render(request, 'billboardapp.html', {'form': form})
```

on billboard_index I have a form with one field in which user puts a date. This date is then used as an input for a webscraper. I save the scraped data in the database, this works (I know this code will break in couple instances, but I'll deal with this later). Next I want to follow the spotify authorization flow, so I redirect to a url at spotify/authorization, it works. This gives me the code back when I'm redirected to spotiauth.html. At the same time, I print there all the database entries that were added during scraping. This is the spotiauth view:

```
def spotiauth(request):
Positions100 = Top100model.objects.all()
print(request)
context = {
    'positions': Positions100,
}
return render(request, 'spotiauth.html', context=context)
```

I have couple questions:

1. How do I pass additional arguments to the spotiauth view? I tried

   ```
   return redirect(to=url, date=date)
   ```

But I can't access it in spotiauth view. So I don't really want to pass it in the url, I just want it as an argument to another function, is this doable?

2. Is this the actual way to go about it? Not sure this is the simplest thing to do.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: not sure about this you could try this ```url = '{0}?{1}```. it's a way of formatting a string with values on older versions of python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Authentication is something that should be handled in a generic way, and not individually and explicitly per request. This is because you don't want to duplicate the authentication code in every request that needs authentication.

Lucky you, you are using Django which already comes with an authentication and authorization layer, and a great community that creates great libraries such as [django-allauth](https://django-allauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) that integrate OAuth2 authentication into Django's authentication layer.

OAuth2 against Spotify is what you are trying to implement here. Just

1. include [django-allauth](https://django-allauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) via pip,
2. configure the Spotify provider in the settings following their documentation,
3. include their URLs for login and registration (see their docs)

... and you should be able to sign into your app using a Spotify account.

For your regular views then, the decorator `login_required` would then suffice.

Django-allauth will do the following:

- for users who sign in via OAuth2 providers, regular Django accounts will be created automatically
- you can see these users in the Django admin, in the same list as the regular Django users
- you can manage the configuration of the OAuth2 provider configuration via the Django Admin - django-allauth brings a model with an admin for it
- django-allauth brings additional functionality like email verification, multiple email address management etc.

If you want to style the login and registration pages, you can implement your own templates using django-allauth's templates as basis.

Comment: I actually reached that part of documentation today! Indeed, I am lucky haha :) I think it's just getting experience with the framework. It's not trivial ;) Thank you !!

Comment: Your on a good way. Trying to do it yourself in the beginning is also good - it lets you appreciate the work that is covered by those libraries.

Comment: Absolutely true. I remember back in the day I used to write code in BASIC for microcontrollers. You know, changing registries etc. Then I started using libraries and my problem with that was that I no longer knew what was going on exactly. I think there's a balance in that :)